# How to convert an "IO (Either e a) into an ExceptT e m a

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm using [Control.Monad.Except](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2017-03-01/mtl-2.2.1/Control-Monad-Except.html) and am stuck in a place where I have to force execution of an `ExceptT AppError m a` action to obtain an `IO` action, and then to wrap it back again into an `ExceptT AppErr m a`. If you're wondering why this is required, it is because the underlying library function that I need to run, only accepts IO action. In this case it would be `Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.withTransaction :: Connection -> IO a -> IO a`

How do I write the conceptual equivalent of the following:

```
type AppM = ExceptT AppError (ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO))

runAppM :: Env -> AppM a -> a

withTransaction :: AppM a -> AppM a
withTransaction appm = do
  conn <- getDbConnection
  env <- getEnv
  liftIO $ PGS.withTransaction conn $ runAppM appm
```

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Excepted type: ExceptT AppError (ReadertT Env (LoggingT IO)) a
Actual type: ExceptT AppError (ReadertT Env (LoggingT IO)) (Either AppError a)
```

Comment: The title and body of your question are completely different questions.

Answer (score -1):

Use the constructor `ExceptT : m (Either e a) -> ExceptT e m a`

```
withTransaction :: AppM a -> AppM a
withTransaction appm = do
  conn <- getDbConnection
  env <- getEnv
  ExceptT $ PGS.withTransaction conn $ runAppM appm
```

Comment: Still gives an error: `Expected type: ExceptT AppError (ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO)) a // Actual type: ExceptT AppError IO a`

Comment: This answer is wrong, presumably because the question in the title is not the same as the actual question in the body.

Comment: `PGS.withTransaction conn $ runAppM appm` evaluates to an `IO (Either e a)` and it needs to be converted to an `ExceptT e m a`. Is there a gap in my understanding of what's happening here?

Comment: I see. `ExceptT $ liftIO $ PGS.withTransaction conn $ runAppM appm` is right. `liftIO` lifts `IO (Either e a)` to `ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) (Either e a)` and then `ExceptT` lifts it to `AppM a`